# Is it possible to get sentiment for emojis using IBM Watson NLU?

Tags: ibm-watson, sentiment-analysis, watson-nlu

I am using IBM Watson to get sentiments of social media texts. But many of these texts are just emojis. Currently, I am not able to get any sentiment for emojis. I get unsupported text language error. Is there anyway to get the sentiments for emojis using Watson NLU?

```
{
  "language": "unknown",
  "error": "unsupported text language: unknown",
  "code": 400
}
```

Comment: You can integrate IBM Watson NLU with IBM Power AI Vision to analyze images as emojis

Answer (score 0):

Provided you are sending them in as utf characters in a utf string, then it really depends on whether the NLU corpus has been trained to recognise them - I don't know if it is, however ...

I tried testing the following strings for document sentiment:

```
“I am feeling  today”  - Sentiment : -0.823 : Negative
“I am feeling  today"  - Sentiment : +0.939 : Positive
```

You need some text for the service to recognise the language and hence which corpus to use.